# Optaplanner CVRPTW is not considering ready/due time

Tags: optaplanner

After creating a custom  CVRPTW XML file I found that optaplanner is not considering the ready and due time for the given solution. After trying with many variations of ready time, due time and service duration, opta planner always calculate the same output.

You can see an example:

[image]

At the XML file, we are filling like this:

```
<VrpTimeWindowedCustomer id="848"><id>2</id><location class="VrpAirLocation" reference="4"/><demand>20620</demand><readyTime>0</readyTime><dueTime>432000</dueTime><serviceDuration>13650</serviceDuration></VrpTimeWindowedCustomer>
```

You can see the sample XML data here: https://codeshare.io/xZspP

Maybe we are wrong on how to understand the number format?

Comment: Is that the time window of the vehicle? I am not sure if that constraint is added - I faintly recall that the txt importer class detects that and automatically reduces the dueTime of all customers or something (which isn't ideal). We should indeed improve the example, feel free to create a jira for that.

Comment: No,  this is the time window of a customer.  The full file is here https://codeshare.io/xZspP